# Initialize a database with a script using Spring JDBC fails

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, spring-boot, sql-scripts

I am trying to initialize my database with a view and a rule following [75.3 Initialize a database using Spring JDBC](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html).

> 75.3 Initialize a database using Spring JDBC
>
> Spring JDBC has a DataSource initializer feature. Spring Boot enables it by default and loads SQL from the standard locations schema.sql and data.sql (in the root of the classpath). In addition Spring Boot will load the schema-${platform}.sql and data-${platform}.sql files (if present), where platform is the value of spring.datasource.platform, e.g. you might choose to set it to the vendor name of the database (hsqldb, h2, oracle, mysql, postgresql etc.). Spring Boot enables the fail-fast feature of the Spring JDBC initializer by default, so if the scripts cause exceptions the application will fail to start. The script locations can be changed by setting spring.datasource.schema and spring.datasource.data, and neither location will be processed if spring.datasource.initialize=false.

This section says that if I put a `schema-postgresql.sql` it should initialize my database with the script that the file contains.

Unfortunately the script ends with the following error

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: syntax error at end of input SQL state
>     Position: 169
>     at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2310) ~[postgresql-9.4.1209.jre7.jar:9.4.1209.jre7]
>     at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2023) ~[postgresql-9.4.1209.jre7.jar:9.4.1209.jre7]
>     at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:217) ~[postgresql-9.4.1209.jre7.jar:9.4.1209.jre7]
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:421) ~[postgresql-9.4.1209.jre7.jar:9.4.1209.jre7]
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:318) ~[postgresql-9.4.1209.jre7.jar:9.4.1209.jre7]
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:310) ~[postgresql-9.4.1209.jre7.jar:9.4.1209.jre7]
>     at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:473) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
>     ... 64 common frames omitted

However if I run this script from `pgAdminIII` there are no errors and the view with the corresponding rule are created without any problem.

What am I doing wrong here?

This is the structure of my Spring Boot example to reproduce it.

### src/main/java/com/example/model/Person.java

```
package com.example.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1334414548362400146L;

    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name = "";

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String surname = "";

}
```

### src/main/java/com/example/model/PersonRole.java

```
package com.example.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class PersonRole implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3953147119216643027L;

    @EmbeddedId
     private PersonRoleKey primaryKey;
}
```

### src/main/java/com/example/model/PersonRoleKey.java

```
package com.example.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.ForeignKey;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;

@Embeddable
public class PersonRoleKey implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2105526364632711640L;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "person_fk"))
    private Person person;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

}
```

### src/main/java/com/example/model/Role.java

```
package com.example.model;

public enum Role {
    ADMIN, USER;
}
```

### src/main/java/com/example/DemoApplication.java

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

### src/main/resources/application.properties

```
#Database configuration
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username: postgres
spring.datasource.password: postgres
spring.datasource.platform: postgresql
spring.datasource.continue-on-error: false

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql: true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl: true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update
#default means org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy: default
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.auto_quote_keyword: true
spring.jpa.show-sql: false
```

### src/main/resources/schema-postgresql.sql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_peoples_roles AS
 SELECT p.id,
    p.name,
    p.surname,
    pr.role
   FROM (person p
     JOIN personrole pr ON ((p.id = pr.person_id)));

CREATE OR REPLACE RULE insert_v_peoples_roles AS
    ON INSERT TO v_peoples_roles DO INSTEAD ( INSERT INTO person (id, name, surname)
  VALUES (new.id, new.name, new.surname);
 INSERT INTO personrole (person_id, role)
  VALUES (new.id, new.role);
);
```

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.2.Final</hibernate.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

The whole code could be downloaded from [here](http://speedway.magma-net.pl/demo.zip).

## EDIT

Based on the [poz's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1499698/pozs) I changed the `schema-postgresql.sql` to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_peoples_roles AS
 SELECT p.id,
    p.name,
    p.surname,
    pr.role
   FROM (person p
     JOIN personrole pr ON ((p.id = pr.person_id)));

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_into_v_people_roles() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO person (id, name, surname) VALUES (new.id, new.name, new.surname);
  INSERT INTO personrole (person_id, role) VALUES (new.id, new.role);
  RETURN new;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS insert_v_peoples_roles ON v_peoples_roles;
CREATE TRIGGER insert_v_peoples_roles INSTEAD OF INSERT ON v_peoples_roles FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_into_v_people_roles();
```

But it produces another error, exactly like predicted.

> ERROR: unterminated quoted string at or near "$$ BEGIN INSERT INTO person (id, name, surname) VALUES (new.id, new.name, new.surname)"

Comment: My wild guess would be that somehow the unstandard syntax of PostgreSQL's `CREATE RULE` statement confuses JDBC and/or Spring (which may want to split the statements on `;` to only execute them one-by-one). If that's the case, then it tries to execute only the half of your  `CREATE RULE` statement, which can cause the error you got. If you use a recent version of PostgreSQL, you can try to use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger (**without** dollar-quoting) instead of rules (*with* dollar-quoting, the same problem could occur).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint. However it seems impossible to create `INSTEAD OF` trigger without actually using double dollar quoting, because it is needed for defining the function that is afterwards used after `EXECUTE PROCEDURE` part of the trigger. Isn't it simply a bug in spring boot? I should be able to execute any native database script using this mechanism as it is supposed to do exactly such a thing. Am I wrong?

Comment: You can create functions with bodies single quoted, like `CREATE FUNCTION ... AS 'body'` see [the exact syntax here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS) -- dollar quoting is just for convenience anyway (it will be harder to use single quoted constants within a single quoted constant) -- For your questions: no, spring just uses JDBC under the hood, which is designed to execute only 1 statement at a time (there is a batch functionality for other uses). Many JDBC based frameworks use nasty workarounds for this reason...

Comment: ... f.ex. liquibase's `endDelimiter` with `splitStatements` on the [`<sql>` tag](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html). Unfortunatly, I'm not familiar with Spring boot, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Changing double dollar quotes to single quote solved the problem. If you sum up your comments and post them as answer I will accept it and upvote it. I have learned a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [pozs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1499698/pozs) has not posted his own answer and some time has passed I am doing it by myself.

Changing the `CREATE RULE` to an `INSTEAD OF` triggered and `$$`-quoting to `'`-quoting solved the problem. The only issue was that I had to escape all the apostrophes inside function definitions. Was not that big of a pain though.

Comment: my problem seems like you mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42674803/spring-boot-database-initialization-mysqlexception-for-trigger but im MySQL. Please help